# Перевод Bit-Plane Encoder

Tags: перевод, информатика

Помогите перевести "Bit-Plane Encoder" в этом предложении:

> The compressor consists of two functional parts, depicted in figure
>   2-1, a Discrete Wavelet Transform module that performs decorrelation,
>   described in section 3, and a Bit-Plane Encoder which encodes the
>   decorrelated data, described in section 4.

Контекст можно посмотреть [здесь](http://public.ccsds.org/publications/archive/122x0b1c3.pdf), мое предложение находится в конце страницы 2-1.

Последнее слово ("Encoder") для меня понятно - это кодирующее устройство. А вот "Bit-Plane" для меня не ясно. Спасибо!

Comment: http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=bit-plane

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_plane

Comment: Спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли!

Answer (score 1):

Если верить [этой](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_plane) статье, то `Bit-Plane` соответствует определению `битовая плоскость`. Так что корректным переводом станет `кодировщик битовых плоскостей`

> Bitplane is sometimes used as synonymous to Bitmap; however, technically the former refers to the location of the data in memory and the latter to the data itself

если был использован подобный контекст, то можно использовать в качестве перевода `Карта битов`

Answer (score 1):

Нет, это не bitmap, bitmap совсем другая штука (и переводится как растр).

А здесь можно перевести как битовая плоскость. Там даже определение есть:

Bit plane b consists of the b-th bit of the two’s-complement integer representation of each DC coefficient, and the b-th bit of the binary integer representation of the magnitude of each AC coefficient.

Если что, я программист.